# PyTorch BERT model with distributed fused LAMB algorithm fails when CUDA graph is enabled

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

A PyTorch BERT model with distributed fused LAMB algorithm which applies CUDA graphs fails to run when CUDA graph is enabled.

**Code**: [passcode:jngl](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1RMV_myLa5Ij9y0a5s3yFvw). (Suppose downloaded into "/home/root/bert-mlperfv1.0")

**Dataset**: [passcode:8na1](https://pan.baidu.com/s/13VQ9LekWdL8XSIY9HpQ6mw)(very large, about 1T) or [passcode:vm91](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1Iz7IIJoUtqac3GemO_IdOA)(incomplete but can run). (Suppose downloaded into "/dataset")

**Environment**: Python installed with PyTorch and Apex.You may need to build [Apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex) by your self by the following command line to enable all the additional features which are needed:

```
pip install -v --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" --global-option="--fast_multihead_attn" --global-option="--fmha" --global-option="--distributed_adam" --global-option="--deprecated_fused_adam" --global-option="--distributed_lamb" --global-option="--deprecated_fused_lamb" ./
```

in the git cloned Apex root directory within the python environment. It seems Apex can be compiled with PyTorch 1.9.0.

**Hardware**: At least 2 NVIDIA A100 GPUs.

**Reproduce the error**: Firstly run the following several lines of commands(supposing we are using only two NVIDIA A100 GPUs):

```
sudo sh -c "ulimit -n 999999 && exec su $LOGNAME"
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1
```

and then enter into the directory "/home/root/bert-mlperfv1.0" and confirm that --output_dir option in the file:"./scripts/run_pretraining_fp16_ph2_distributed_fused_lamb_also_disable_dense_seq_out_max_steps_200_pure_command_use_cuda_graph_train_batch_size_6_disable_allreduce_post_accumulation_cuda_graph_mode_full_iteration_use_original_run_pretraining.sh" does exist or modify it to an existing directory.

Then run the command:

```
sh ./scripts/run_pretraining_fp16_ph2_distributed_fused_lamb_also_disable_dense_seq_out_max_steps_200_pure_command_use_cuda_graph_train_batch_size_6_disable_allreduce_post_accumulation_cuda_graph_mode_full_iteration_use_original_run_pretraining.sh
```

to get the error output:

```
......
Torch distributed is available.
Torch distributed is initialized.
Torch distributed is available.
Torch distributed is initialized.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".//run_pretraining_original_correct_use_our_own_distributed_fused_lamb.py", line 1599, in <module>
    args, final_loss, train_time_raw = main()
  File ".//run_pretraining_original_correct_use_our_own_distributed_fused_lamb.py", line 1220, in main
    grad_scaler.scale(loss).backward()
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/training_results_v1.0_pytorch_mlperf_bert_model_enable_all_apex_features_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 255, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/training_results_v1.0_pytorch_mlperf_bert_model_enable_all_apex_features_test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 149, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: CUDA error: operation would make the legacy stream depend on a capturing blocking stream
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
......
```

The code runs smoothly without enabling CUDA graph. But when CUDA graph is enabled, it fails.

This code is a slightly modified version from [...](https://github.com/mlcommons/training_results_v1.0/tree/master/NVIDIA/benchmarks/bert/implementations/pytorch). What could be the cause of the error when the full iteration mode of CUDA graph is enabled?